# ckeditor not showing beacuase of visibility attribute

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, textarea

I am using ckeditor in my page and the problem is that it doesn't show up! When I checked the inspect element on firefox, I found out that the visibility of the text area is set as invisible

```
element {

visibility: hidden;

}
```

So I tried to handle it by writing the code below for me text area which has the ed1 as its id

```
visibility: visible;
```

But then when I refreshed the page and checked again, my piece of code was lined out as the one that can't be executed
I tried several ways of including the ckeditor and using the script tag, thinking maybe the problem lays there but it was useless.
Thank you so much for the help in advance
this is my code by the way:

```
<div id = "myckeditor">
    <textarea name = "ed1" id = "ed1">
        Write your opinion on this...
    </textarea>
</div>
<script src="js/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('ed1');
</script>
```

Comment: CKEditor is working fine with `visibility: hidden;`. Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/qdndP/153/)

Comment: thanks, well then what is the reason mine is not working?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help I became sure the problem wasn't that, I had a small problem with directory, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Hector Barbossa I became sure the problem wasn't with the visibility and was with the directory